# $State.Current on initial page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

When my app starts up for the first time $state.current returns an empty string for the name and '^' for the url. this is causing problems because i am trying to select my menu item based on the name of the current state. does my configuration seem correct? if also tried removing the abstract property.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        data: {
            allowAnonymous: false
        }
    })
    .state('app.meal-plan-list', {
        url: '/dashboard', templateUrl: 'app/modules/meal/meal.meal-plan-list.html'
    })


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access $state.current inside controller, then use like this,

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $state.current = toState;
  }
);
```

and you can also use with `$rootScope`